# Infinite loop in Basic Greedy Algorithm for TSP

Tags: python, algorithm, infinite-loop, greedy, traveling-salesman

I am trying to implement basic greedy algorithm for Travelling Salesman Problem in Python 2.7.

I have a dictionary called **d_dict = {(city1,city2):distance}** that stores distances between cities. Here, all cities are connected to one another. I simply need to get to the closest neighbour till all cities are covered and then head back to the start city. Here, for convenience, the start city is 1, i.e. **st = 1**. There are two lists, **rem**, that stores uncovered cities and **cov**, that stores cities in the order they are covered.

I have defined a function called **basic_greedy(x)** that takes city x as start city, computes its distance to all uncovered cities (since every city is connected to every city in this case) in list rem, and then the nearest neighbour is removed from rem, appended to cov and made the next start city. This function is called iteratively till rem becomes an empty list (i.e. all cities are covered). The start city (or **root**) is simply appended at last to cov. Here is my code:

```
#create two lists - 'covered' or 'cov': to store cities as they are covered in order.
#'remaining' or 'rem': list of uncovered cities.

cov = []
rem = [ x for x in range(1,size+1)]

global st
st = 1 #start city, initialized as 1
root =  st     #root of the graph - start of the tour


#######################################
#basic greedy search

#function definition - basic greedy search algorithm for the travelling salesman problem

def basic_greedy(x):

    #rem.remove(x)

    try:
        r = rem.index(x)
        del rem[r]
    except:
        pass

    cov.append(x)
    print (cov,rem)

    m=1
    chg = 0  #a temporary variable, counts number of changes in value of st
    if x < size:
        m = d_dict[(x,x+1)] #variable m shall keep track of the smallest distance
    elif x == size:
        m = d_dict[(x,x-1)]

    for k in rem:
        if d_dict[(x,k)] < m:
            m = d_dict[(x,k)]
            st = k


########################################

while len(rem)!= 0:
    basic_greedy(st)

cov.append(root)
print "Basic Greedy Search Tour: ",cov  #THE FINAL SEQUENCE
```

However, when I run this, I get an **infinite loop**, that is just 1's appended infinitely. What is the error in the code?

(P.S. I have tried multiple ways yet have been unable to spot the error for days)

**edit:** Here is the dictionary for 12 cities:

```
(1, 1) : 0 ,
(1, 2) : 32 ,
(1, 3) : 7 ,
(1, 4) : 13 ,
(1, 5) : 15 ,
(1, 6) : 21 ,
(1, 7) : 5 ,
(1, 8) : 30 ,
(1, 9) : 40 ,
(1, 10) : 31 ,
(1, 11) : 9 ,
(1, 12) : 14 ,
(2, 1) : 32 ,
(2, 2) : 0 ,
(2, 3) : 40 ,
(2, 4) : 21 ,
(2, 5) : 3 ,
(2, 6) : 8 ,
(2, 7) : 32 ,
(2, 8) : 25 ,
(2, 9) : 3 ,
(2, 10) : 5 ,
(2, 11) : 16 ,
(2, 12) : 10 ,
(3, 1) : 7 ,
(3, 2) : 40 ,
(3, 3) : 0 ,
(3, 4) : 5 ,
(3, 5) : 9 ,
(3, 6) : 12 ,
(3, 7) : 12 ,
(3, 8) : 20 ,
(3, 9) : 30 ,
(3, 10) : 50 ,
(3, 11) : 21 ,
(3, 12) : 31 ,
(4, 1) : 13 ,
(4, 2) : 21 ,
(4, 3) : 5 ,
(4, 4) : 0 ,
(4, 5) : 9 ,
(4, 6) : 11 ,
(4, 7) : 20 ,
(4, 8) : 6 ,
(4, 9) : 29 ,
(4, 10) : 27 ,
(4, 11) : 25 ,
(4, 12) : 35 ,
(5, 1) : 15 ,
(5, 2) : 3 ,
(5, 3) : 9 ,
(5, 4) : 9 ,
(5, 5) : 0 ,
(5, 6) : 4 ,
(5, 7) : 30 ,
(5, 8) : 10 ,
(5, 9) : 6 ,
(5, 10) : 8 ,
(5, 11) : 15 ,
(5, 12) : 9 ,
(6, 1) : 21 ,
(6, 2) : 8 ,
(6, 3) : 12 ,
(6, 4) : 11 ,
(6, 5) : 4 ,
(6, 6) : 0 ,
(6, 7) : 35 ,
(6, 8) : 7 ,
(6, 9) : 8 ,
(6, 10) : 17 ,
(6, 11) : 14 ,
(6, 12) : 13 ,
(7, 1) : 5 ,
(7, 2) : 32 ,
(7, 3) : 12 ,
(7, 4) : 20 ,
(7, 5) : 30 ,
(7, 6) : 35 ,
(7, 7) : 0 ,
(7, 8) : 50 ,
(7, 9) : 53 ,
(7, 10) : 30 ,
(7, 11) : 6 ,
(7, 12) : 10 ,
(8, 1) : 30 ,
(8, 2) : 25 ,
(8, 3) : 20 ,
(8, 4) : 6 ,
(8, 5) : 10 ,
(8, 6) : 7 ,
(8, 7) : 50 ,
(8, 8) : 0 ,
(8, 9) : 20 ,
(8, 10) : 40 ,
(8, 11) : 32 ,
(8, 12) : 34 ,
(9, 1) : 40 ,
(9, 2) : 3 ,
(9, 3) : 30 ,
(9, 4) : 29 ,
(9, 5) : 6 ,
(9, 6) : 8 ,
(9, 7) : 53 ,
(9, 8) : 20 ,
(9, 9) : 0 ,
(9, 10) : 2 ,
(9, 11) : 15 ,
(9, 12) : 7 ,
(10, 1) : 31 ,
(10, 2) : 5 ,
(10, 3) : 50 ,
(10, 4) : 27 ,
(10, 5) : 8 ,
(10, 6) : 17 ,
(10, 7) : 30 ,
(10, 8) : 40 ,
(10, 9) : 2 ,
(10, 10) : 0 ,
(10, 11) : 15 ,
(10, 12) : 4 ,
(11, 1) : 9 ,
(11, 2) : 16 ,
(11, 3) : 21 ,
(11, 4) : 25 ,
(11, 5) : 15 ,
(11, 6) : 14 ,
(11, 7) : 6 ,
(11, 8) : 32 ,
(11, 9) : 15 ,
(11, 10) : 15 ,
(11, 11) : 0 ,
(11, 12) : 4 ,
```

Comment: How are you going to "spot" the error? You should try adding more debug print statements to ensure every step of your program is functioning correctly.  Also, I wouldn't `pass` on exceptions, until you're finished with development.

Comment: @AlexW I have tried that as well. I have tried debug print statements right from the beginning (which I have excluded here to keep the code snippet concise) The error I get is that when I print (cov,rem) I get an infinite loop where 1 is infinitely appended to rem. Also, I had to pass the exception since a simple use of rem.remove(x) gave the error 'x not in list' (which i don't understand again) (I found this "pass" solution on stack overflow itself :p) I did it to be able to proceed and spot the error

Comment: @AlexW I am unable to spot the cause of the infinite loop

Comment: @AlexW please see this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\R.K.singh\Desktop\AIsearch\basic_greedy.py", line 86, in <module>
    basic_greedy(st)
  File "C:\Users\R.K.singh\Desktop\AIsearch\basic_greedy.py", line 59, in basic_greedy
    rem.remove(x)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: Can you post the input?  I.e. the `d_dict` values you are using?

Comment: @AlexW the values are read from a file and then put into the dictionary, but I'll post them.

Comment: @AlexW please see the edit, I have added the dictionary